# Is it possible to show the contents of a directory without changing into it?

Tags: directory, ls

I'd like to show the contents of a folder without first changing into it. for example:

```
---- Documents
        |
        |
        L_ Essays
```

If I'm in `Documents`, how can I show the contents of `Essays` with a single command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ls Essays/
```

works from within `Documents`.  A tiny snippet of FreeBSD's `ls` man page:

```
 ls [ .... ] [file ...]
```

> `DESCRIPTION`
>        For each operand that names a file of a type other than directory, `ls`
>        displays its name as well as any requested, associated information.  **For
>        each operand that names a file of type directory, `ls` displays the names
>        of files contained within that directory**, as well as any requested, associated information.

Comment: Just add a slash? Really?

Comment: just `ls directory`, the slash is not mandatory even, as, in your case, the file `Essays` is of type directory.

Comment: Oh, I see, so the name of the target directory is what does it.

Comment: @sr_: the slash is required if the directory is a symbolic (soft) link.

Comment: @HaiVu: Thank you, I wasn't aware of this `:)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include the directory name in the listing, too:

```
find Essays/ -maxdepth 1
```